# Find emails with Google's smartlabels

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

It's possible to search one's gmail Inbox for Google's smartlabel, using the search criteria : `label:^smartlabel_receipt` for instance.

But these labels don't appear when being listed using this API :
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

Is there a hidden way to still reference this Internal Gmail label?

Comment: It may not available in the API yet. I tried getting the list and did not get any `smartlabel` in the result. Maybe it is only a feature within gmail page to help the user organize their mails.

Comment: Can you use google's extended search command in the All Mail folder to find it?

Comment: Could you publish a link to such extended search commands ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions  You want SEARCH X-GM-RAW.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Gmail API's [`messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and append a query parameter. For example, like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<userId>/messages?q=label:^smartlabel_receipt
```